# Multiple elements using the same click function at once. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Raphael JS, but I think this is pure JavaScript or maybe jQuery question.

I have two elements a text and an circle(ellipse) and I am using a variable to store them for later usage.

So, I was thinking that instead of repeating myself over and over again I will create an array  and use it on click.

But it is not working. How to solve this problem and assign onclick for every variable(object) in my array?

```
var circle = paper.ellipse(350, 320, 95, 90);
var text = paper.text(350, 320, "My text");

var myArray = [circle, text];
myArray.click(function () {
    window.location = "http://somewebsite.com";
});
```

Comment: i doubt arrays have a `.click` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery $.each function can help you with this;

```
$.each(myArray, function(i, v) {
    v.click(function() {
        window.location = "http://somewebsite.com";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You needn't store the objects in an array if you just want to keep them around, you've already referenced them with two variables: `circle` and `text`. Define the function once and then assign it to any element that uses it:

```
var circle = paper.ellipse(350, 320, 95, 90);
var text = paper.text(350, 320, "My text");

function clickFunction()
{
    window.location = "http://somewebsite.com";
}

circle.addEventListener("click", clickFunction);
text.addEventListener("click", clickFunction);
```

Or, using jQuery:

```
circle.click(clickFunction);
text.click(clickFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with raphaelJS ...

```
var circle = paper.ellipse(350, 320, 95, 90);
var text = paper.text(350, 320, "My text");
var click_set = paper.set();
click_set.push(circle);
click_set.push(text);

click_set.click(function(){
 // do what you want ... this function will automatically be bound to all the elements that //you push in the set
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the elements and append the handler to each of them. No need for any libraries.

```
var circle = paper.ellipse(350, 320, 95, 90);
var text = paper.text(350, 320, "My text");

var myArray = [circle, text];
var handler = function () {
    window.location = "http://somewebsite.com";
};

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i].onclick = handler;
}
```